# Moving icons down to bottom of the page

Tags: html, css, wordpress, footer

Im developing a site using Wordpress and id like to move the social network icons to the bottom of the page (icons are over at the top of the left hand panel)

http://www.chessfusco.com/flowers/

Ive dug around on this site and tried some of the things people have suggested in relation to sticking a footer at the bottom of the page etc but i just cant seem to get it to work!

Would anyone mine giving me a hand?

Yous
Chess

Answer (score 1):

Just add this in your markup

```
<div class="dock-panel-wrap" style="position: fixed; bottom: 0;">
```

See [image]

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to this class:

```
.dock-panel-wrap {
    padding: 0 20px;
    position: absolute;/*Add position absolute*/
    bottom: 0;/*Add bottom at 0*/
    width: 100%;/*Set width to 100%*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know for sure without knowing what theme you use. A good start would be to check 'Appearance' > 'Widgets'. With any luck, the social icons will be a widget, that you can simply move to the footer 'sidebar'

**Edit:**

I can see that you're using the 'epix' theme. Your first place to ask would be the support forum - http://help.themeva.com/?envato_item_id=5783556. After all you've paid for the theme, you're entitled to some support.

Answer (score 0):

In ul.dock-panel class replace

```
position:relative;
```

with

```
position:absolute;
bottom:0px;
```